# pivot table returns more than 1 row for the same ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a sql code which I am using to do pivot. Code is as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT PersonID
,MAX(pivotColumn1)
,MAX(pivotColumn2) --originally these were in 2 separate rows)
FROM(SELECT srcID, PersonID, detailCode, detailValue) FROM src) AS SrcTbl
PIVOT(MAX(detailValue) FOR detailCode IN ([pivotColumn1],[pivotColumn2])) pvt
GROUP BY PersonID
```

In the source data the ID has 2 separate rows due to having its own ID which separates the values. I have now pivoted it and its still giving me 2 separate rows for the ID even though i grouped it and used aggregation on the pivot columns. Ay idea whats wrong with the code?

So I have all my possible detailCode listed in the `IN` clause. So I have null returned when the value is none but I want it all summarised in 1 row. See image below.

[image]

Comment: sample data and the expected result please

Comment: Either use a `pivot` or use `group by`, but not both together.  If you use `pivot`, you should eliminate the column in the subquery that makes the two rows look different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If those are all the options of `detailCode` , you can use conditional aggregation with `CASE EXPRESSION` instead of `Pivot`:

```
SELECT t.personID,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.detailCode = 'cas' then t.detailValue END) as cas,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.detailCode = 'buy' then t.detailValue END) as buy,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.detailCode = 'sel' then t.detailValue END) as sel,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.detailCode = 'pla' then t.detailValue END) as pla
FROM YourTable t
GROUP BY t.personID
```

Comment: but there are some instances where more than 2 rows, hence why I asked the question. Sorry should've cleared that when I posted question

Comment: Yea, you should have posted data sample.. @Faiz

Comment: the thing is I want to be able to use pivot because I will have an increase in the detailCode. Henceforth is there a solution to this using pivot?

Comment: @everyone I just sorted it. It was the create date of each row that was a bit different and it wasnt allowing me to see the result how I wanted

Comment: You can use this for as many options you like, as long as they are limited and you know them @faiz